# creating custom command line in django that does not check database connectivity

Tags: django

I have a requirement whereby sometimes our database engine goes down and I need to automate a certain procedure to through django's command line. Am trying to write a code that would run to perform some reporting and start up some services and I need to run in from django context so i can use django's library and project setting.

Any ways, is there a way to develop a command line that can be executed without checking if database exists or perhaps i can trap the exception? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

NVM, I looked at source code for the command "shell" and saw "requires_model_validation" parameter. I used it in my command and it went through, here is an example

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    args = '<No arguments>'
    help = 'This command will init the database.'
    requires_model_validation = False

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            print 'ss'
        except Exception :
            raise CommandError('Cannot find default database settings')
```